# Navigating through pages in Xamarin without changing the entire content of the page

Tags: c#, xamarin

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNKac.png

Is there a way that I can do this in Xamarin.Forms like the picture above? In UWP, I can do this by using Frame element and I can navigate through pages without changing the entire content.

Comment: Do you want to do this using Xamarin Forms?

Comment: sorry, it's a new account. I cannot embed an image yet. But yes, it's for Xamarin.Forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use [MasterDetailPage](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/navigation/master-detail-page/). You have a MasterPage (on the left) and DetailPage(on the right) that you can change when you press your item in the Master.

This is how you can create in C# a MasterDetail

```
public class MainPageCS : MasterDetailPage
{
    MasterPageCS masterPage;

    public MainPageCS ()
    {
        masterPage = new MasterPageCS ();
        Master = masterPage;
        Detail = new NavigationPage (new ContactsPageCS ());
    }
}
```

The MasterDetailPage.Master property is set to a ContentPage instance. The MasterDetailPage.Detail property is set to a NavigationPage containing a ContentPage instance.

Otherwise if you don't like MasterDetail, you can "simple" use a [Grid](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid/) with 2 rows X 2 columns. Then you can use a ContentView for your menu (it should use `Grid.SetRowsSpan (menuContentView, 2);` so your contentView fill 2 rows.

Then you can use a Label for the title and another ContentView for your "Page"

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for ***Master Detail Layout*** like attached? Created in ***Xamarin.Forms***. Help me understand your question!

### [image: Master Detail Layout]

Comment: that's it!! That's the one I'm looking for if that panel with phones in it changes only and not the entire page

Comment: That's what you got! Happy! Be sure to go through this
[link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1100122/Xamarin-Master-Detail-Page) and don't forget to add master behaviour property to your master page to get a native look & feel. Cheers!

Comment: Make sure you Accept this as answer if it satisfies your needs. Thanx!